# Learning about DB2 triggers

Tags: db2

Hi I am trying to figure out the syntax for triggers. I have two tables one called tagged_in and the other notification. So I want to make a trigger where when an insert is called in tagged_in I want to insert a tuple in notification.

Answer (score 1):

The manuals are available at the [DB2 InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp).  Did you read the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html) statement information yet?  If not, why not?  If so, what did you try, and what error did you get?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER TEMP
     AFTER INSERT ON TAGGED_IN
This far as I got I want say insert into notifications values(value from taggen in, "")

Comment: @Louie: Good - you've decoded the first three lines of the syntax diagram.  Now proceed to the next one - you will need a REFERENCING clause for the newly inserted values so that you can add them to the other table.  Note that your trigger name is not appropriate - though syntactically it is fine.

Comment: is it REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS TEMP2

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER TEMP
AFTER INSERT ON TAGGED_IN
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS TEMP2
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS VALUES(TEMP2.EMAIL_ID, 'YOU GOT TAGGED');

Comment: That looks about right - what did DB2 have to say when you ran it?  Also, once you've finished, you should probably transfer your trigger into the question - or possibly an answer of your own - so that people can see what you did that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER
     AFTER INSERT ON TAGGED_IN
     REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_TAG
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN ATOMIC
       INSERT INTO NOTIFICATION
         VALUES (NEW_TAG.FIELD1,NEW_TAG.FIELD2);
     END
```